# Definition of the Metropolis matrix

Tags: probability-theory

> Define a stochastic matrix $p$ on $E$ by
>
> $$p(x,y) = \begin{cases} q(x,y) \min\Bigl(1, \frac{\pi(y)q(y,x)}{\pi(x)q(x,y)}\Bigr)\,, & \text{if } x\neq y, \, q(x,y) > 0\\
>   0\, , & \text{if } x\neq y,\, q(x,y) = 0, \\
>   1- \sum_{z\neq x}p(x,z)\,, & \text{if } x=y\, .
> \end{cases}$$
>   $p$ is called the *Metropolis matrix* of $q$ and $\pi$.

I don't understand the third row of this definition... why isn't it just:
$$p(x,y) = \begin{cases} q(x,y) \min\Bigl(1, \frac{\pi(y)q(y,x)}{\pi(x)q(x,y)}\Bigr)\,, & \text{if } x\neq y, \, q(x,y) > 0\\
  0\, , & \text{if } x\neq y,\, q(x,y) = 0, \\
  p(x,x)\,, & \text{if } x=y\, .
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although yes they are equivalent (although see second paragraph), the first formulation makes it clear to you where $p(x, x)$ comes from.  Namely, the first two rules specify all the values of $p(x, z)$ where $x \neq z$.  Then $p(x, x)$ is just what you need to add to get $1$.

I should add they are equivalent so long as you already know $p$ should be a probability matrix, if not, $p(x, x)$ could be anything in your second formulation.

Comment: of cooooooooourse... I was blind...